# Run website on Apache and Python Rest Services on NGINX on HTTPS

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, https

I have a website (React) running on Apache on SSL. I have used LetsEncrypt to get a SSL certificate for my website. On the same box, I also have some REST services running on NGINX. How can I run both Apache and NGINX on HTTPS to use the same certificate. IF i create a self-signed certificate, the modern browsers dont seem to like it.

In a nutshell, this is what I'm trying to do (could be a bad way, so happy to smacked on the head and corrected)

1. Run website on www.blah.co.uk --> hits the website running on Apache
2. the website uses rest services running on nginx...something like
   www.blah.co.uk:another_port/users/12345
   3.Primarily I'm keen on having both the UI and the Python/REST running on HTTPS.

Is this feasible?

Comment: Why do you have both Apache and nginx? You only need one of these.

Comment: I have a separate team building the UI in React and they have deployed the server on Apache....whereas my stuff (Python REst services) are running on NGINX.

Answer (score 0):

You can run both servers on different ports without any problems with the same certificate. Just specify the same certificate in both server configurations.

The reason is that the certificate contains only the hostname, not a port.

Comment: I have done it, but I get an error saying 443 is being used by another process. I want the main website (on React) to internally call the rest services running on nginx using something like this "website_name.co.uk:port/users/124"

Comment: As I wrote, you must specify different ports. Port 443 is default for https, so specify a different port for the rest services on nginx.